# Connectivity between Vb.net and Ms-access

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to know, could we establish database connectivity using VB.Net 2005 and MS-access 2007?

If yes then, how could we do that? I am looking for the whole procedure.

If no then, why can't we do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You lost me at "could we did".  There's goodness in the Project + Add Reference, COM tab.  Microsoft Access xx.x Object Library.

Comment: I think your question is a little vague.  A more specific single request with at least some pseudo code of what you are attempting to do would help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do.  [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) fully supports VB.Net as well as Access 2007.  You can also use the [Office Data Access](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734) install to enable direct access from ADO.NET to .mdb and .accdb files (as well as Excel spreadsheets).